# What difference between add and sink.add?

Tags: dart

I can't figure out what difference between `.add` and `.sink.add`?

Example:

```
StreamController myStreamController = StreamController();
stream = Stream<int>.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) => t + 1).take(3);
```

When I should do:

```
myStreamController.sink.add(myStreamController);
```

and when:

```
myStreamController.add(myStreamController);
```

Answer (score 3):

It does the same. The purpose of the sink property are to provide a restricted interface for you streamcontroller:

> Returns a view of this object that only exposes the StreamSink
>   interface.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-async/StreamController/sink.html